# Loop controller inside While controller in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a while controller that stops after running for 5 seconds.
This while controller works fine when inside it, there is one sampler or one HTTP request.

Now I want to have a loop controller inside this while controller. But now, the while controller doesn't stop after 5 seconds, and the script runs for the number specified in loop controller.

Is there any way my loop controller stop working when the while controller trigers in 5 seconds?

Here's the schematic of my test plan. I want that "search" request stops after 5 seconds (the condition inside while controller), no matter the specified number in loop controller.

[image]

PS. The code inside JSR223 Sampler1 calculates the maximum time:

```
max = ${__timeShift(,,PT5S,,)}; 
vars.putObject("max", max);
```

And this is the logic inside While Controller:

```
${__groovy( now = ${__time()}; max = vars.get("max") as long; now <= max,)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why would you need the Loop Controller if While Controller generates loops itself?
2. Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into JSR223 Test Elements or __groovy() function otherwise [you might get unexpected behaviour](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler).

If you want to limit While Controller's number of loops to some specific maximum value just include it into your condition clause.

1. In the JSR223 Sampler:

   ```
   max = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000L
   ```
2. In the While Controller:

   ```
   ${__groovy( now = System.currentTimeMillis(); max = vars.getObject("max"); now <= max && (vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') as int) < 10,)}
   ```

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter)